# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buenas tardes,

Desde hace varios dias vengo con este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una aplicacion que consume un wcf pero a la hora de cargar la data en el jqGrid genera error "HTTP status code: 500" y despues saca la ventana de la imagen.

Navengando en internet he realizado cualquier cantidad de sugerencias pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo (actualize por nuget el asp.net web APi a la 2.2 y )

Cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria que revises el `web.config` deberias tener una seccion `dependentAssembly`

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Es allí donde deberías validar que version defines y cambiarlo a la version que tienes referencida